# error de sintaxis en la linea 19 en el print , me sale un error united does not match any outer indentation level y no se a que se deba

Tags: python

"""código para crear una piramide de asteriscos, encuentro un error en la linea 19 que dice united does not match any outer indentation level y no se a que se deba"""

```
 n=int(input('ingrese n ')) 
while not (n%2==1) and n>0:
     print ('n debe de ser impar y mayor que 0')
     n=int(input('ingrese n'))

a=1 
while not a==n+2 :
   b=a
   while not b==1:
               print (end='*')
               b=b-1
  print (end='*')
  b=0
        while not b=(n-a)*4:
         print (' ')
         b=b+1
         b=a
            while not b=1:
        print (end='*')
          b=b-1
       print (end='*')
       a=a+2
```

Answer (score 1):

Te esta advirtiendo acerca de la identacion, que es la forma en que le muestras al compilador que linea pertenece en determinado bucle.

En la linea 19 aparece corrido el WHILE muy adelante, y la siguiente linea muy atras. Esto le indicaria al compilador que la siguiente linea esta fuera del bucle WHILE. Entonces el WHILE no tendria sentido. Al poner el print mas atras del while, pareciera que no forma parte del bucle.

Para solucionarlo, solo debes acomodar el codigo. Las lineas que vayan dentro de un bucle o funcion deben ir 4 espacios(o una tabulacion) mas adelante del bucle.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

En python la indentación **no tiene una función estética**, sino que es la que **determina que sentencias están dentro de un bloque** y cuales no.

Para indentar, puedes utilizar **espacios** (el número que tu consideres) o **tabuladores**. Antes de empezar, decide el método que vas a utilizar, después **utiliza siempre el mismo criterio** (te evitarás muchos errores como éste en el futuro).